# unset std object whole key based condition check

Tags: php, arrays, object

trying to filter data from std object to get result only with status = Active

here is my data =

```
$newresults  =

array {
    
    [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 30508
                [status] => Active
            )
    
        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 30509
                [status] => InActive
            )
    
        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 30510
                [status] => Active
            )
    
}
```

in foreach loop i need to get new array of std object with status = active only

so far i am trying to do this with

```
foreach ($newresults as $key => $value) {
            if($value->status == 'Inactive')
                unset($newresults[$key]);

            }

            $newresults[]=$value;
        }
return $newresults;
```

thanks in advance i am sure i can do it this way but i might be doing mistake somewhere

expected output =

```
array {
    
    [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 30508
                [status] => Active
            )
  
        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 30510
                [status] => Active
            )
    
    }
```

Comment: Do you want an additional aray containing the active records or modify the existing array to have only the active records...?

Comment: @Juan modify the existing array to have only the active records

Comment: Ok. And Have you tested your code...?

Comment: @Juan yes i am getting an error if i execute code with the above code = Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Comment: You have a "return" while you are not in a function. If you delete this "return"...? And if you display your array with "var_dump()" for example...?

Comment: @Juan even var dump not working = var_dump($newresults);die(); = Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var_dump' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248350/discussion-between-juan-and-troy-roy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```php
$newresults = array_filter($newresults, function ($v) { return $v->status == 'Active'; });

print_r($newresults);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 30508
            [status] => Active
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 30510
            [status] => Active
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/BYJLh)

If you want the array to be re-indexed starting at 0, just use [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) on the result.

Comment: working 100% by changing var $new_results = array_filter($newresults, function ($v) { 
            return $v->status == 'Active'; 
        });

Comment: @TroyRoy oops sorry I always put an `_` where there shouldn't be one... :) I'll just correct the code in the answer

Comment: @TroyRoy anyway, glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

That should work where you just remove those "Inactive" ones.

```
foreach ($newresults as $key => $value) {
    if ($value->status == 'Inactive') {
        unset($newresults[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not working still returning InActive results too